# fast batch image resizer

Tags: images

looking and cant find the perfect one.
i have 100 gig of 4K image-sequence to process.

found [imagizer2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagizer2/) on sourceforge. multi-thread but not 64bit (does matter?).
i guess the fastest one will be using intel's IPP image core lib .

i am on windows, but if some crazy fast linux option is available i'll consider (benchmarks?).

included benchmarks i ran on a test batch of 100 5k (4.3MB) files

- [image resizer for windows](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/) = 20sec
- [batch picture resizer](http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize) = 30sec
- [imagizer2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imagizer2/) = 64sec
- [irfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) = 80sec
- [Fast image sizer](http://adionsoft.net/fastimageresize/)= 110 sec
- [imageMagick-6.7.1-Q16x64](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) = 149sec

Comment: You mentioned image sequence - do you want to process individual images, or combine them into video sequences? If the latter, I would do the transformations during production with virtualdub.

Comment: yes, my orginal plan was to do this all in command line using ffmpeg `ffmpeg -i d:\g\25\g_%%04d.jpg -r 15 -s hd720 -vcodec libx264  -fpre "libx264-hq.ffpreset" -crf 16 Day01_720.mp4`  
but fmpeg is hard coded to support images no larger then 5012pixels. hence the resize.

Comment: i actually prefer [avisynth](http://www.avisynth.org/) for image sequence work, its so powerful.

Comment: Penny drops! 4K line film quality images, not 4kb images! Yes, avisynth is great and supplied with virtual dub. ffmpeg is open source, so the 5012 pixel limit can be modified and recompiled, or the authors could increase the default limit. It shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: adding more benchmakrs: VIPS and GraphicsMagick
http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Speed_and_Memory_Use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767106/resizing-images-jpeg-or-decompressed-image for referance

Comment: Super fast!! https://github.com/jarun/imgp

Comment: interesting, imgp uses pillow, here are some pillow benchmarks https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/

need to revisit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great stats - thanks for the references. Perhaps too late but you didn't mention ImageResizer results (from Codeplex) suggested with Batch Picture Resizer above. (not the same as the mentioned "crapware") I started using it after MS stopped updating their Image Resizer. But certainly don't have have the speed and volume needs - just clean and quick resizes for email attachments and such.

Comment: thanks, i lost the original dataset but on comparable set seems this is crazy fast. too bad its not scriptable (but sourcecode is available, so...)

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) for converting 1 GB of tiff files to smaller GIF ones each night. Takes only some minutes.

A sample command woulöd look like this (I use this to convert pictures for my digital photo display)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IrfanView\i_view32.exe" "C:\Pictures\Best\*.jpg" /resample=(720,540) /aspectratio /convert="C:\Temp\miniDisp\*_rsz.jpg"
```

This does resize all JPG files from C:\Picutres\Best\ to 720x540 and save them as C:\Temp\miniDisp\ *OrgFilename*_rsz.jpg.

The command line switches IrfanView understands can be found inside the online help (see Index - Command line options) or online [here](http://from8to5.blogspot.com/2007/12/dos-batch-irfan-view-command-line.html)

Comment: irfan is also my day to day tool, but irfan = 80sec  for same test.

Comment: Well, that's really long compared with the other programs. Thanks for the tests.

Comment: irfanview also my viewer and batch processor of choice though virtualdub is also an essential tool. It could be used to combine image sequences into a video with the benefit of delta compression, and an image could be retrieved by indexing a frame.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how it will compare in the benchmark dept but you may want to give [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) a try using the "convert" or "mogrify" tools. It sounds like it makes good use of 64 bit, number of cores and such.
All I know is that it is really powerful and feature full. I can resize in place or add options like resample filters and file type conversions.

```
mogrify -format jpg -filter Cubic -resize 20%x20% rgb-?.png
```

Comment: i love cmd, but im also benchmark junky...   mageMagick-6.7.1-Q16x64 = 149sec

Comment: I guess I'm not surprised as it seems ImageMagick is more the Swiss army knife than the scalpel. Well done on the question and benchmarks.

Answer (score 4):

Check out these programs:

1. [Batch Picture Resizer](http://www.rw-designer.com/picture-resize).
2. [Image Resizer](http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/).

Resizing images using batch files: [Batch Resize](http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/batch.php).

Comment: i took 100 5k pictures:    
batch picture resizer = 30sec     
imagizer2 = 64sec

Comment: Try this one: Fast Image Resizer (http://adionsoft.net/fastimageresize/). This one also seems promising: http://www.obviousidea.com/windows-software/light-image-resizer/

Comment: Fast image sizer= 110 sec

Comment: light-image-resizer is crapware

Comment: False advertising then. Try the batch method I put in the edited comment. If that doesn't help then I'm out of options. Otherwise, if the batch picture resizer took 30 sec, to resize 500 MB word of images (assuming each of the 100 images was 5 Mb. ea), it should take 1 hour, 40 minutes to resize all of the 100 GB of pics you have. That's not too bad?

Answer (score 1):

Parallel can be used to speed up batch conversions with imagemagick.

Shrink every *.jpg in a directory such that neither the height nor width is bigger than 1080 pixels:

```
parallel mogrify "{}" -resize 1080x1080 ::: *.jpg
```

Using convert to create seperate smaller files:

```
parallel convert "{}" -resize 1080x1080 "{.}-small.jpg" ::: *.jpg
```

Note that this applies to GNU parallel, not the version packaged in Debian's moreutils, which has a different syntax & less features. See the man page for more information on parallel.

Answer (score 0):

vips is faster, for me:

```
$ header sample.jpg 
sample.jpg: 8888x5000 uchar, 3 bands, srgb, jpegload
$ for i in {1..100}; do cp sample.jpg t$i.jpg; done
$ time vipsthumbnail --size 1280 t*
real  0m14.672s
user  0m17.631s
sys   0m0.988s
```

Speed is limited by jpeg encode/decode, which (thanks to libjpeg) is single-threaded. You can get it going quite a bit quicker if you run several vipsthumbnail in parallel:

```
$ mkdir a b c d e
$ for j in a b c d e; do for i in {1..20}; do cp sample.jpg $j/t$i.jpg; done; done
$ time (for i in a b c d e; do vipsthumbnail --size 1280 $i/t* & done; wait)
real  0m5.258s
user  0m18.557s
sys   0m0.891s
```

This is on a 2012 imac, but there are windows binaries too.

http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/